# WebAPI JsonConverter for x-www-form-urlencoded not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've created simple model with `JsonConverter` attribute:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "my_to")]
    public string To { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "my_from")]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "my_date")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateConverter))]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and my converter:

```
public sealed class UnixDateConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!CanConvert(reader.ValueType))
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException();
        }

        return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds((long)reader.Value).ToUniversalTime().LocalDateTime;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return Type.GetTypeCode(objectType) == TypeCode.Int64;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var datetime = (DateTime) value;
        var dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(datetime.ToUniversalTime());
        var unixDateTime = dateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        writer.WriteValue(unixDateTime);
    }
}
```

When I send request from Postman and I set content type as `application/json` everything works fine - my converter works fine, debugger stops at breakpoint in my converter, but I must use `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Is there an option to use `JsonConverter` attribute inside model when sending data as `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Why do you even have a json converter when you use x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: @MarcusH I've tested my API using `application/json` but now I must handle `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I thought this should work, problem is it isn't. So what would be other options to do this? I need to support custom name mapping (different name of field in request and different name in my model, like PropertyName attribute) and datetime converter

Comment: Are you sending JSON data with your `Content-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded` request or are you sending form-post data?

Comment: @spender I'm using `x-www-form-ulrencoded`.

Comment: If you're using `x-www-form-urlencoded`, I don't understand why you want to use a JSON converter.

Comment: @Amy as I wrote before I've build my api assuming it will use `application\json` but things changed and I must use `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I thought that if I'll change content type my api will work, but it isn't. Right now I'm trying to get it working or getting alternative.

Comment: @Amy I've build prototype using Newtonson JSON assuming I'll be able to decide what content type I'll accept. It was quite easy doing that - just couple of properties on my model and everything works. But I must support `x-www-form-urlencoded` so right now I must change my model properties names and fields because I don't have to automatically convert unix timestamp to datetime. That's why I posted this question. I'd like to get JsonConverters to work or I'd liek to know if there is an alternative.

Comment: The point is that you don't normally use a JSON converter with `x-www-form-urlencoded`.  You need a [media formatter](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters), not a `JsonConverter`.

Comment: @Amy I've used `Media Converters` before, but to format output of my method, not the input (data I post to my method). Can I use Media Converter to map and convert my model?

Comment: Did you solve this, cause i have removed my JSON converters and its still not accepting `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @SoliQuiD as I remember correctly I've build custom generic ModelBinder (look for IModelBinder). I'll try to search that code and post it here as an answer.

Comment: @SoliQuiD I've added my code as an answer. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by creating custom  model binder that implements [IModelBinder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.imodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx)

Here is generic version of my binder:

```
internal class GenericModelBinder<T> : IModelBinder where T : class, new()
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof (T))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var model = (T) bindingContext.Model ?? new T();

        JObject @object = null;

        var task = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>().ContinueWith(t => { @object = t.Result; });
        task.Wait();

        var jsonString = @object.ToString(Formatting.None);
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonString, model);
        bindingContext.Model = model;

        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is sample usage:

```
[Route("save")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Save([ModelBinder(typeof (GenericModelBinder<MyModel>))] MyModel model)
{
    try
    {
        //do some stuff with model (validate it, etc)
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        DbContext.SaveResult(model.my_to, model.my_from, model.my_date);
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK", new TextMediaTypeFormatter(), "text/plain");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
        Logger.Error(e, "Error saving to DB");
        return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if JsonProperty and JsonConverter attributes worked, but they should.

I'm aware that this might not be the best way to do it, but this code worked for me. Any suggestion are more than welcome.